# Opening Stock Value In Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am working on Cost of goods sold using Powerbi.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/pmb7u1thsag1kq1/Cost+of+goods+sold.pbix/file

Above is my file which i uploaded on mediafire.

i am taking the average price by using average function year wise.
If you see in File.

```
| GName       | Year | Opening Stock | InQty | OutQty | InItemValue | Average Value | Closing Stock | Closing Stock Value | Opening Stock Value | Cost of Goods Sold |
|-------------|------|---------------|-------|--------|-------------|---------------|---------------|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------|
| Bahria Town | 2016 |               | 4454  | 3586   | 126610299.8 | 28426.20113   | 868           | 24673942.58         | 0                   | 101936357.2        |
| Bahria Town | 2017 | 868           | 6379  | 6547   | 166903971.5 | 23030.76743   | 700           | 16121537.2          | 0                   | 150782434.3        |
| Bahria Town | 2018 | 700           | 9129  | 8709   | 271932546.3 | 27666.3492    | 1120          | 30986311.11         | 0                   | 240946235.2        |
| Bahria Town | 2019 | 1120          | 9333  | 9393   | 313226466.8 | 29965.22212   | 1060          | 31763135.45         | 0                   | 281463331.4        |
| Bahria Town | 2020 | 1060          | 10192 | 10136  | 362950101.2 | 32256.49673   | 1116          | 35998250.35         | 0                   | 326951850.8        |
| Bahria Town | 2021 | 987           | 8882  | 8468   | 404199067.4 | 40956.43605   | 1530          | 62663347.16         | 0                   | 346819100.5        |
```

In Above as you can see i just took the Average Value

```
Average Value = ([Opening Stock Value]+[initemvaluee])/([inqtyy]+[Opening Stock])
```

and closing stock value

```
Closing Stock Value = [Average Value] * [Closing Stock]
```

When i calculate the closing stock value of previous year its give me error.

```
circular dependency was detected: Measure: 'mak_stockInHandValue'[Average Value], Measure: 'mak_stockInHandValue'[Opening Stock Value], Measure: 'mak_stockInHandValue'[Average Value].
```

Any Suggestion to see the closing stock value in the field of opening stock value ?????

I am working on this from more than 2 weeks.

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you are calculating closing stock value of previous year?

Comment: If you think any new suggestion please you also give me that. !

Comment: Opening Stock Value = CALCULATE([Closing Stock value],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('date'[Date].[Date])

Comment: Read this two article:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-circular-dependencies/